# How to sent a soap request using angular2 and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm looking for a way to send SOAP request to a web service, with a WSDL. Is it possible to do that with Typescript 2 and Angular 2 ?

i have searched for it but i didn't found.

can you please help us how to send a soap request using angular 2 and type script?

Comment: In general it is possible to do anything in Typescript and Angular that is possible in JS. TS gets compiled to JS itself after all and you can even embed native JS-scripts in TS and in Angular-templates.

Comment: But it is generally not recommended to do that and almost everyone recommends to use a microservice as proxy, returning a RESTful response to the client. For example see https://jimdowney.net/2013/12/04/the-restfulness-of-single-page-applications/

Comment: can you please help me with a sample code how to sent a soap request using angular and type script

Comment: But i have existing soap services i need to make use of that only.so it would be helpful if you provide any sample code how to sent a soap request using angular 2 and type script

Comment: I have never used SOAP over JS for the listed reasons. Here is a google video result for "soap request javascript": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qk2Vz9kSVYQ

Comment: But i need a way to call the soap request in my project.Because we have already soap webservice exist we need to make use of that.can any one help me how to call the soap webservice using angular2 and typescript

Comment: "we need to make use of that". Why? You can make a simple proxy microservice with spring boot. If you want to handle everything on the front-end, you can lookup any resource online for handling SOAP requests with Javascript. perhaps you can even use a Node.JS library. To use a js-file in Typescript just make a require statement. For example to get a reference to an express-server: `const express = require('express'); let app = express();` Same way you can put a script in the assets-folder and say `require('assets/my-soap-proxy.js')`.

Comment: Also keep in mind your SOAP server has to set CORS-headers, otherwise your browser will reject the response. If you have no access to the SOAP Server and only to its API, then you have to use a proxy microservice in between anyway.